# How many homomorphisms are there of $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$ into $S_4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know $|\mathbb{Z}_{24}|=24$, and $|S_4|=24$. I am unable to find the number of homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$ into $S_4$. Is there any general rule to find the number of homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_{n!}$ into $S_n$? Or $S_n$ into $\mathbb{Z}_{n!}$?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The answer depends on the number of cyclic subgroups of $S_4.$

Comment: As a follow up, let $G$ be any group of order $n$. How many homomorphisms from $\Bbb Z_n$ to $G$ are there?

Comment: Up to that I am fine. Then what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Say $h$ is a homomorphism of $\Bbb Z_{24}$ into any group at all.  Once you decide $h(1)$, you get no more choices; the rest of the homomorphism is completely determined.  Why?  Because if you want to know $h(3)$, say, you can compute it from $h(1)$, since $$h(3) = h(1+1+1) = h(1) \ast h(1) \ast h(1).$$  If $h(3)$ were anything else, then $h$ would not be a homomorphism.

So to count the possible homomorphisms $h$, it's enough just to identify the possible values for $h(1)$.  Does that give you enough to go on?

Comment: How many cyclic subgroups of $S_4$?

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: After knowing number of distinct cyclic subgroups. That number is the number of homomorphisms from $Z_{24}$ to $S_4$. Probably the number is 17.

Comment: It is not 17. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: The number of group morphisms is 24. If not then correct me.